# Why does this svg become so large in Chrome when the stroke-width is changed?

Tags: html, svg

Here I have an SVG path, created from a polygon in lat-long degrees, rendered twice, once with a stroke-width of 6e-5, and once with a stroke width of 7e-5.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="-93.146752514 -41.665871084 0.006181792 0.006973032">
    <path d="M -93.144986629000002 -41.665658802999999 L -93.145040273999996 -41.662124163000001 -93.146692513999994 -41.659406928000003 -93.146606684000005 -41.659006146000003 -93.140652180000004 -41.658958052000003 -93.140630721999997 -41.664897388999997 -93.141059874999996 -41.665225999999997 -93.141070604000006 -41.66577101 -93.144932984999997 -41.665811083999998 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="6e-05" fill="none" />
</svg>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="-93.146752514 -41.665871084 0.006181792 0.006973032">
    <path d="M -93.144986629000002 -41.665658802999999 L -93.145040273999996 -41.662124163000001 -93.146692513999994 -41.659406928000003 -93.146606684000005 -41.659006146000003 -93.140652180000004 -41.658958052000003 -93.140630721999997 -41.664897388999997 -93.141059874999996 -41.665225999999997 -93.141070604000006 -41.66577101 -93.144932984999997 -41.665811083999998 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="7e-05" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

In Firefox, I see two copies of the same image. In Safari, I see only the 7e-5 polygon. In Chrome, I see the 6e-5 polygon, and the 7e-5 polygon becomes a huge black mass.

The Chrome issue is the most troublesome, as it means that inserting that svg anywhere overflows and covers the elements around it. Any ideas on what might be causing the different renderings, and how I can keep it from happening consistently?

Comment: How can keep it from happening? Avoid big numbers.

Comment: when It displays differently in browsers it means the `SVG` is not valid for some reason.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your two SVGs display just fine under FF (60.0.1, Linux) and Chrome (66.0.3359.181, Linux) and look nearly the same. Opened your code as .html file, and also put the two SVG fragments into individual .svg files. There must be something weird going on here, such as CSS overriding SVG display properties, or maybe you're opening your example content as a single .svg file (though Chrome will reject that as invalid XML)